# Unable to bind event handler at init

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, audio

I have a form in which audio preview elements are created dynamically.  I want to execute code after the audio elements have been processed by the browser.  The following works:

***Works if executed after audio elements have been created***

```
  $('audio').on('loadeddata', ->
    alert "test audio"
  )
```

but it only works if I bind the event after the element has been created.  I am looking for a way to bind the event to all future 'audio' tags at document onload.  The following does not work:

***Never Works***

```
$(document).on('loadeddata', 'audio', ->
  alert "test audio"
)
```

***The following always works***

```
$(document).on('click', 'audio', ->
  alert "test audio"
)
```

My goal is to be able to bind [these events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadeddata.asp) once when my document is loaded.  Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

***Edit***

because I am using rails with turbolinks I execute The above snippets with both ready and onload events.  So the code is:

```
reload = ->
  #relevant code here

$(document).on 'page:load', reload

$ -> reload()
```

Comment: Instead of `$(document).ready()` try binding the code inside `window.onload`.

Comment: thanks @Bongs, I was actually already doing both.  See edit

Answer (score 0):

Start your event handling after your document has fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('loadeddata', 'audio', function(){
      alert "test audio"

     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding those events inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // bind your events here
});
```